# Register a .com.au domain in Azure

Tags: azure, domain-name

According to the [custom domain docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app), domains on Azure are restricted to `com`, `net`, `co.uk`, `org`, `nl`, `in`, `biz`, `org.uk`, and `co.in` TLDS.

I've been trying to register a `.com.au` domain name without success.

Does anyone know

- why it is not possible ?
- is it likely to be any time soon ?

**UPDATE**
I've submitted a [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/33539956-support-original-and-country-code-top-level-domain) to see if we can widen the list of possible domains. Please vote if you think this is a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean you want to register a domain name `.com.au`?

Comment: Yes. Was the question unclear?

Comment: The following top-level domains are supported by App Service domains: com, net, co.uk, org, nl, in, biz, org.uk, and co.in.

Comment: I knew that per my question. A answer to the two lines appended with a ? character was what I was actually looking for.

Comment: Are you want to buy domain name `.com.au` from Azure?

Comment: Yes. Is this not the same thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74088/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-ordinaryorange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been trying to register a .com.au without success.

For now, Azure does not support this.

If you want to buy a domain not list in the available domains, you can't buy it from Azure.